# What happens when a TransactionScope times-out

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

In C# I am using the TransactionScope(). If the TransactionScope() times-out does the transaction get committed or is it rolled back?

Comment: Only one of those actions would be *sane* given that no normal transaction should time out and there's no way to know whether the activity that the transaction should be protecting has been completed (after all, if it was completed, why wasn't the transaction committed before the timeout?)

Comment: Why would the system commit a transaction that is mid-way through it's processing? That's almost guaranteed to corrupt data and serves no discernible purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard time-out value is 10 minutes. If the TransactionScope time-out is triggered, the transaction will do a roll-back. If you didn't commit the transaction, the state will not change (ACID principles).

ACID-principles on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

It is possible to change the time-out in your .config file using the maxTimeout.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As documented on MSDN the transaction is aborted i.e rolled back and a TransactionAbortedException exception is thrown.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149852%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx